# Difficulty using GDB in Windows terminal. GDB quits itself after running the program without waiting for my further commands

Tags: c, gdb

I have included my source code at the bottom. I am also copy pasting my terminal below with line numbers that I added myself in bold to try to make myself clear. I would expect the (gdb) prompt to stay alive in line 10, but it doesn't. It keeps running until line 14 as shown below. i.e the terminal itself gives quit command at line 10 and it keeps running until it stops at line 14. How do I make it stop at line 10? in other words How do I stop the terminal from giving itself the 'quit' command to (gdb)?

**Terminal copy paste below**

```
PS C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents\Visual_Studio_C_Projects\Test> gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) Cygwin 7.9.1-1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"... 
Reading symbols from a.exe...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/c/Users/arunmozhi/Documents/Visual_Studio_C_Projects/Test/a.exe
**Line 1:**[New Thread 2136.0xdbc]
**Line 2:**[New Thread 2136.0x2958]
**Line 3:**[New Thread 2136.0xf20]
**Line 4:**[New Thread 2136.0x2a5c]
**Line 5:**[New Thread 2136.0x13f4]
**Line 6:**[New Thread 2136.0x109c]
**Line 7:** Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
**Line 8:** 0x004011d4 in main () at test.c:8
**Line 9:** 8 sum+=data[i];
**Line 10:** (gdb) quit
**Line 11:** A debugging session is active.
**Line 12:** Inferior 1 [process 2136] will be killed.
**Line 13:** Quit anyway? (y or n) EOF [assumed Y]
**Line 14:** PS C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents\Visual_Studio_C_Projects\Test>
```

**Source code below**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int data[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i=0, sum=0;
    for ( i=0; i>=0; i++)//incorrect code intentionally written to learn debugging with gdb
    {
        sum+=data[i];
    }
    printf("Sum = %d.\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you expect to happen. The debugger states that your program is exited because of a segmentation fault (which you deliberately caused). Then, on "line 10", you input the command `quit` to quit the `gdb` session.

Comment: Hi olov, Thanks for answering my question. That is where the problem is, in "line 10". I didn't input the quit command in line 10. The quit command was loaded automatically by the windows terminal. How do I stop this automatic quit command by the terminal please?

Comment: Ok, this sounds like an odd behavior in that case. What kind of shell is run in the terminal? For me Windows Terminal just is the application which can encapsulate Powershell, Cmd, Ubuntu 18 (if you have Windows Subsystem for Linux) etc.

And is this happening in any other cases?

Comment: Hi Olov, I am using Windows Powershell. OS is Windows 10 32 bit. This is happening for any source code that I try and this automatic loading of "quit" happens only after "run" command. This automatic quit doesn't happen after any other command like list, break, print etc but obviously those commands are of no use to me until I have run the program. I hope I have answered your question. Do you need any other information? I would appreciate any help please. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the `.gdbinit` file that is executed before any `gdb` startups. Try to run gdb with a flag to not read any `.gdbinit`-files: `gdb --nx a.exe`. You can read more about the gdbinit file here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html

Comment: Hi Olov, I tried gdb --nx a.exe to no avail. Still experiencing exactly the same problem. "quit" loads automatically and gdb exits to terminal after running the program. I will read about the .gdbinit. Thanks for your time anyways. I appreciate it. Please drop me a line if you come up with any other idea. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out how to fix this issue. All it needed was updating the cygwin gdb package to current version from https://cygwin.com/install.html. My OS is Windows 10 32 bit and so I used setup-x86.exe. Took less than 5 minutes to update the package and it worked like a treat, but to get to the point of updating the package took 5 days of mind numbing research. The older version which didn't work was 7.9.7-1 (2015). The new version is 9.2-1 (2020). Now the (gdb) doesn't exit on its own after the run command and it waits for me to tell it what to do. I am able to pass commands like `list`, `print` etc and able to get expected response. I am copy pasting the terminal below after fixing the issue.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\arunmozhi>cd documents
C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents>cd visual_studio_c_projects
C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents\Visual_Studio_C_Projects>cd test
C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents\Visual_Studio_C_Projects\Test>ls
Test.c  a.exe
C:\Users\arunmozhi\Documents\Visual_Studio_C_Projects\Test>gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 9.2-1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.exe...
(gdb) run
Starting program: 
/cygdrive/c/Users/arunmozhi/Documents/Visual_Studio_C_Projects/Test/a.exe
[New Thread 10188.0xe98]
[New Thread 10188.0x195c]
[New Thread 10188.0x2c8c]
[New Thread 10188.0x14c0]
[New Thread 10188.0x3eac]

Thread 1 "a" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004011d4 in main () at test.c:8
8               sum+=data[i];
(gdb) list 5
1       #include<stdio.h>
2       int main()
3       {
4           const int data[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
5           int i=0, sum=0;
6           for ( i=0; i>=0; i++)
7           {
8               sum+=data[i];
9           }
10          printf("Sum = %d.\n",sum);
(gdb)
11          return 0;
12      }
(gdb) print i
$1 = 209155
(gdb) print sum
$2 = -532459950
(gdb) set var i=2
(gdb) print i
$3 = 2
(gdb)
```