# gdb quits automatically after running the program

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

I'm trying to debug a simple program of several line with gdb from the command line.
The problem is that whenever I run the program it runs the program and then automatically assume that I wanted to quit and quit gdb for me.

- I'm using gcc compiler and I've updated the version (which solved another problem that I had).
- to clarify the problem is that it is not me who entered the `quit` command after the `run` command, gdb generates it automatically without asking me and then assumes yes.
  [image: Code show the process mention above.]

Comment: Maybe you have some fancy `.gdbinit` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740754/make-gdb-quit-automatically-on-successful-termination/5286038 ?

Comment: Seems like it is the same problem the other way around though I can't figure out how to cancel it from their answers, any suggestions?

Comment: Check your `.gdbinit` files. There are might be several though...

Comment: suggest: 1)  before entering the `run` command, set a breakpoint on the beginning of the program: `br main`  and also set a breakpoint on the last executed line of the program

Comment: Please do not post links to images.  Rather, copy/paste the actual text into the text of your question

Comment: what is the linked image of your commands to `gdb` expected to show?   Right after the `run` command, you entered `quit`!   What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: That's exactly the problem! That's not me who enter `quit`  it does that without asking me. I'm setting `br main` and then gdb verifies that it's actually set the breakpoint and then I run the program and it just does everything normal and continue to `quit` anyway then `assume yes` automatically.

Comment: Are you debugging a cygwin executable? If yes, could you try it in the cygwin terminal? If not, why are you using a cygwin gdb?

Comment: @ssbssa 
I've tried to run it in the cygwin terminal and it worked, so first of all thank you because that a great advancement though I would like to understand why it doesn't work on the command-prompt. 
I'm following an udemy course and the instructor runs it via the command-prompt (tried to ask him for solution and he couldn't answer)

Comment: What gdb version do you use? Because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515071/1983398) says it fixed a similar problem by updating. If you also use an older version, why?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by running gdb in a cygwin window rather than a Windows command window. I get the cygwin window by running (i.e., double-clicking on) mintty.exe, which on my machine is at

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe
```